# Terminal appears to ignore autoproxyurl setting

Tags: terminal, python, proxy

I can't get easy_install to install anything as it complains it gets a connection refused.:

```
  Searching for BeautifulSoup
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup/: [Errno 61] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'BeautifulSoup' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 61] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for BeautifulSoup
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('BeautifulSoup')
```

If I query the interface I am told the proxy is setup and working (which it definitely appears to be as I can browse, etc.)

```
networksetup -getautoproxyurl Wi-fi
URL: http://webproxy.******.co.uk/wpad.dat
Enabled: Yes
```

Visiting https://pypi.python.org/simple/ manually in a browser also works.

It gets more confusing;

I tried setting the proxies manually instead:

```
djsmiley2k:~$ echo $HTTP_PROXY
webproxy.*******.co.uk:8080
tbowers@tims-mbp:~$ echo $HTTPS_PROXY
webproxy.*******.co.uk:8080
```

Still no dice :/

---

Edit:

More urls appear to be affected, unsure if this is some weird resolving error I just happened to have hit at the wrong time:

```
djsmiley2k:~/bin$ echo $HTTP_PROXY
webproxy.*******.co.uk:8080
djsmiley2k:~/bin$ echo $HTTPS_PROXY
webproxy.*******.co.uk:8080

djsmiley2k:~/bin$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
--2015-05-18 15:30:33--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Resolving bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)... 185.31.18.175
Connecting to bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)|185.31.18.175|:443... failed: Connection refused.
djsmiley2k:~/bin$ wget http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
--2015-05-18 15:31:49--  http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Resolving bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)... 185.31.18.175
Connecting to bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)|185.31.18.175|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

I've checked and I can access the script directly in a browser, trying to go to http forwards me to https automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error strikes again!

I wasn't using the easy_install flags correctly, needs to be:

```
easy_install --user <package>
```

and not  --user.